# Keep getting error A2070 when attempting to zero extend word array to dword

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, masm

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCode: DWORD

.data
    ; Declare your variables here

    arrayW WORD 5, 10, 15, 20
    arrayD DWORD ?, ?, ?, ?

.code
main PROC
    ; Start your code here inside main

    MOV esi, OFFSET arrayW

    MOVZX eax, [esi]
    IMUL eax, 8

    MOVZX ebx, [esi+2]
    IMUL ebx, 8

    MOVZX ecx, [esi+4]
    IMUL ecx, 8

    MOVZX edx, [esi+6]
    IMUL edx, 8

    MOV edi, OFFSET arrayD

    MOV [edi + 0], eax 
    MOV [edi + 4], ebx
    MOV [edi + 8], ecx 
    MOV [edi + 12], edx 

INVOKE ExitProcess, 0
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: You need `word ptr [esi]` to tell it you want the word-src version of movzx instead of the byte-src version.  Also, use a left-shift instead of `imul` to scale by a power of 2.

Comment: I searched but surprisingly couldn't find any exact duplicates.  Maybe someone else will have better luck finding a previous question where ambiguous operand-size was the problem.  I'm pretty sure I've seen some before.